# Update Yes/No field if Date is today

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula, powerapp

I am trying to create an automated SLA field

I have a "Date Requested" Field and an "Outside of SLA" field.

Date Requested is formatted as a Date, Outside of SLA is formatted as a Yes/NO / True/False field.

I am trying to automatically update the "Outside of SLA" field if the "Date Requested" is later than "Today"

I understand it will have something to do with the IsToday() field but im not sure if the logic i am trying to apply will work within PowerApps/Sharepoint.

Is this at all possible? I feel like i am treating this too much like Excel but am pretty new to this. Apologies

Thanks for any advice

Comment: You want to update Yes/No field in PowerApps or you want to create a new calculated field for outside of SLA and update based on Date Requested?

Comment: And the evaluation whether the Outside the SLA should be yes or no should only happen when the list item is created, right?

Comment: I am impartial to either method. A calculated field may prove easier. The Outside SLA should change to YES if the "Requested Date" is on or before today. For instance, requested date = 09/10/2019, todays date = 10/10/2019. Outside SLA = Yes

Comment: Well, as this is evaluated each time the list item is updated most or all will end up being Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calculated column, you could use the following formula:

```
=IF([Date Requested]<=TODAY(),"Yes","No")
```

If you don't want to create calculated column, you could use column formatting to achieve this :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "=if([$DateRequested] < @now, 'Yes', 'No')"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Will it refresh by itself each day without changing any item ? I am sure that calculated columns will not refresh by itself but  not sure about the formatted column. Most of the time we need to keep updating the column as the day passes to keep the column value consistent w.r.t the other column.

Comment: Yes,Column formatting would refresh by itself. When you refresh the page, the formatted column would refresh by itself.

Comment: This is a perfect solution. Thank you for the time with this